# vertx-redis-client 3.7.0: How to use redis transaction

Tags: java, redis, transactions, vert.x

I am using **Vertx 3.7.0** in one of my projects. I have to use redis transaction. I found a method in API: [Redis.batch()](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/redis/client/Redis.html#batch-java.util.List-io.vertx.core.Handler-) hoping that the batch will be executed in a single transaction, but documentation is very very poor.

Could anyone please tell me how to use redis transaction with `vertx-redis-client`?

Can I use [RedisAPI.multi()](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/redis/client/RedisAPI.html#multi-io.vertx.core.Handler-) for transactions? I would really appreciate an example.

Answer (score 2):

Redis transactions follow the redis protocol, which means, you start a transaction with `multi`, followed by your commands and finish with `exec`. If you only have one code flow accessing the redis client, this is sufficient.

However if multiple sources access the client then there's a chance others commands get into the transaction. In order to solve this you can use a `batch` command which sends all commands in an atomic way.